# Import two same name array in JavaScript (Ng2)

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have two Javascript arrays, which names are the same, but it can be found different files.
In HTML I use the script src tags to load the arrays from js files.
I use the loadsh module(or maybe is not important, because it can be found in the window object) in NG2, and unfortunately, it could not load both of them.

For example:

**first.js containts:** 
`var obj = [{"ads":"1"}]`

**second.js containts:** 
`var obj = [{"ads":"2"}]`

Because the loadsh use just the object name not file name:

`(<any>window).obj`

The expected result is, that I have to get in NG2 the two objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple example:

```
var array = [{
  name: "fo1",
  value: "val_1"
}, {
  name: "fo1",
  value: ["val_1", "val_2"]
}, {
  name: "fo2",
  value: "val4"
}];

var output = [];

array.forEach(function(value) {
  var existing = output.filter(function(v, i) {
    return v.name == value.name;
  });
  if (existing.length) {
    var existingIndex = output.indexOf(existing[0]);
    output[existingIndex].value = output[existingIndex].value.concat(value.value);
  } else {
    if (typeof value.value == 'string')
      value.value = [value.value];
    output.push(value);
  }
});

console.dir(output);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but for this example, I have two array variable in two different files, and I don't want to merge them just get the values of the two arrays separately in different variables. Thanks for your help.

Comment: another way is to do a prefix on key to avoid conflict